# SQL inner join multiple tables to one on similar key

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

Im working on a project that includes an Employee table with all the names of all staff keyed by the `EmployeeID` (Int)

I also have a Job table that includes the JobName as string and Foreman, ProjectManager, Project Coordinator, AccountManager as INT that link back to the Employee table.

I need to be able to pull the first and lastname from the employee table for each of the staff assigned to the job.  Ive tried the query below which produces no results.

What am I missing....

```
SELECT
    j.jobsitename,
    j.jobsiteaddress, 
    CONCAT( RTRIM( e.empFirstName ), ' ', RTRIM( e.empLastName ) ) AS Foreman,
    CONCAT( RTRIM( pm.empFirstName ), ' ', RTRIM( pm.empLastName ) ) AS ProjectManager,
    CONCAT( RTRIM( pc.empFirstName ), ' ', RTRIM( pc.empLastName ) ) AS  ProjectCoordinator
FROM
    mpjob AS j 
    INNER JOIN mpEmployee AS e  ON j.jobforeman   = e.empemployeeid
    INNER JOIN mpEmployee AS pm ON j.jobProjMgr   = pm.empemployeeid
    INNER JOIN mpEmployee AS pc ON j.jobProjCoord = pc.empemployeeid
```

Comment: You need to consider the case where an employee doesn't have a foreman (is he/she the foreman?), doesn't have a project manager (is he/she the project manager?), or doesn't have a project coordinator (is he/she the project coordinator?). For these cases where any of those values can be NULL, you should be using a left join (and perhaps using COALESCE to display something other than NULL, like N/A).

Comment: Please use the following link as a guide for how to ask a good question: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Sample data would be great

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   j.jobsitename,
   j.jobsiteaddress,
   e.empFirstName as ForemanFirstName,
   e.empLastName as ForemanLastName,
   pm.empFirstName as PmFirstName,
   pm.empLastName as PmLastName,
   pc.empFirstName as PcFirstName,
   pc.empLastName as PcLastName
FROM mpjob AS j
LEFT JOIN mpEmployee AS e ON j.jobforeman = e.empemployeeid
LEFT JOIN mpEmployee AS pm ON j.jobProjMgr = pm.empemployeeid
LEFT JOIN mpEmployee AS pc ON j.jobProjCoord = pc.empemployeeid
```

LEFT JOIN these values.
INNER JOINs will just return those values if there are a foreman, a PM and a PC. LEFT JOIN shows all data in mpJob even is there are none.

Comment: Worked - Ill will be sure to read up a bit more on the join options.  thank you!